# Add two numbers using bit manipulation

Tags: c#, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm working on the following practice problem from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-without-using-arithmetic-operators/):

> Write a function Add() that returns sum of two integers. The function should not use any of the arithmetic operators (+, ++, –, -, .. etc).

The given solution in C# is:

```
public static int Add(int x, int y)
{
    // Iterate till there is no carry  
    while (y != 0)
    {
        // carry now contains common set bits of x and y
        int carry = x & y;

        // Sum of bits of x and y where at least one of the bits is not set
        x = x ^ y;

        // Carry is shifted by one so that adding it to x gives the required sum
        y = carry << 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Looking at this solution, I understand **how** it is happening; I can follow along with the debugger and anticipate the value changes before they come. But after walking through it several times, I still don't understand **WHY** it is happening. If this was to come up in an interview, I would have to rely on memory to solve it, not actual understanding of how the algorithm works.

Could someone help explain why we use certain operators at certain points and what those totals are suppose to represent? I know there are already comments in the code, but I'm obviously missing something...

Comment: x xor y is already the solution of x + y, unless there are common set bits which are handled by carry.

Comment: @MickyD Computers already have programs, so why bother learning to code at all? After all, most of what we do has already been done, right?

Comment: @spender don't be ridiculous

Comment: @MickyD this question is asking to explain the algorithm, not the code per se. It's also not asking "why would this code be used in production" (so protestations that it wouldn't be are irrelevant), but why it works.

Comment: @harold  _"there is no problem to solve"_

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is an interview question; there is no problem to solve; and it does nothing but attract those to demonstrate their cleverness as the upvotes; comments; and current answers show. [ask]

Comment: @MickyD that is not a close reason. The popular explanation of how Ukkonen's suffix tree algorithm works is also not a "problem to solve". This question could have been constructed better of course.

Comment: @harold _"that is not a close reason"_ -  Incorrect.  _"[there is no actual problem to be solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"_,  Also _"[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)"_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At each iteration, you have these steps:

```
carry <- x & y   // mark every location where the addition has a carry
x <- x ^ y       // sum without carries
y <- carry << 1  // shift the carry left one column
```

On the next iteration, `x` holds the entire sum *except* for the carry bits, which are in y.  These carries are properly bumped one column to the left, just as if you were doing the addition on paper.  Continue doing this until there are no more carry bits to worry about.

Very briefly, this does the addition much as you or I would do it on paper, *except* that, instead of working right to left, it does all the bits in parallel.

Comment: The `<=` may be a little confusing. Perhaps `<-` would be clearer as I often see in algorithmic pseudocode.

Comment: @Prune, thank you for this explanation! It made it all click for me! Thank you!

Comment: @Prune I think you meant to place an XOR-operator on the second line of the code snippet, rather than an addition operator?

Answer (score 4):

Decimal arithmetic is more complicated than binary arithmetic, but perhaps it helps to compare them.

The algorithm that is usually taught for addition is to go through the digits one by one, remembering to "carry a one" when necessary. In the above algorithm, that is not exactly what happens - rather, all digits are added and allowed to wrap, and *all* the carries are collected to be applied all at once in the next step. In decimal that would look like this:

```
123456
777777
------ +
890123
001111 << 1
011110
------ +
801233
010000 << 1
100000
------ +
901233
000000 done
```

In binary arithmetic, addition without carry is just XOR.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a case of Binary Math on the Represenetation in memory:
https://www.wikihow.com/Add-Binary-Numbers

Generally when programming in C#, you do not bother with the "how is it represented in memory" level of things. 55% of the time it is not worth the effort, 40% it is worse then just using the builtin functions. And the remaing 5% you should ask yourself why you are not programming in Native C++, Assembler or something with similar low level capacities to begin with.